# How do you properly create objects with functions in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

We have a Powershell script which loads some configuration for our application from a json file via something like:

```
$ourApplicationSettings=Get-Content -Raw -Path $EnvironmentFile | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now that I have an object which contains all of the settings, I'd like to create a handful of functions which can operate on either the $settings object directly, or some portion of it.

The best practices articles I've read for Powershell state that functions should be of the form: Verb-Noun, which sounds like developers would be expected to write functions like:

```
Get-OurAppSourceDirectory $ourApplicationSettings
DoSomething-OurApp $ourApplicationSettings
```

This seems very counter intuitive as it means that there is no way to easily find all of the functions associated with `OurApp`.

One article proposes one possible way would be to use a function like:

```
function New-OurAppConfig {
     $appConfig = Get-Content -Raw -Path $EnvironmentFile | ConvertFrom-Json
     $appConfig
}
```

but this way I'm not sure how to add member functions so that I could write:

```
$config = New-OurAppConfig
$config.Get-SrcDirectory
$config.Invoke-ActionABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can search for that. `Get-Command *ourapp*`. So that one is not true. As for the second question:

```
$config = New-OutAppConfig
$var = Get-SrcDirectory $config
Invoke-ActionABC $var
```

or alternatively you can do a meta function that calls all those functions, so you could just call it once and thats it.

Also, it seems like what you are trying to achieve can be done with classes in PowerShell. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/04/adding-methods-to-a-powershell-5-class/

Comment: But for Get-Command to work, wouldn't I have to put all of our code into a module and then use Import-Module?

Comment: not necessary, you could simply import those functions, but yes, generally correct. you need to load them into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Add-Member`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) to add script methods to an existing object:

```
$foo = '{"value":23}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$foo | Add-Member -Type ScriptMethod -Name Multiply -Value {
  Param($factor)
  $this.value * $factor
}

$foo.Multiply(2)  # output: 46
$foo.Multiply(3)  # output: 69
```

That approach is a little awkward, though, both because PowerShell prior to v5 wasn't really built for full OO and because calling methods on a configuration object feels odd.

Generally it's more PoSh to read your configuration once at the beginning of your script and then either use it as a global singleton:

```
$cfg = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

function Get-Something {
  ...
  Invoke-Other $cfg.Whatever
  ...
}

Get-Something
```

or make the configuration a mandatory parameter for your functions:

```
$cfg = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

function Get-Something {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)
    $Config
  )

  ...
  Invoke-Other $Config.Whatever
  ...
}

Get-Something -Config $cfg
```

Comment: This doesn't scale well when you have many functions, many of which are either actions or boolean functions.

For instance, let's say that one part of the configuration is an array of objects that describe a set of components that need to be installed. I would like to be able to call $cfg.Install-Components, and $cfg.Enable-Services, etc.

All these global functions seem messy. I'd hate to have to Install-OurAppComponents, Enable-OurAopService, Disable-OurAppServices. Is there a way to override functions? I wouldn't mind Install-Components $cfg, but worry about naming collisions.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [PowerShell v5](http://alexiscoles.blogspot.ch/2015/10/polymorphism-powershell-v5-classes.html). Otherwise PowerShell might not be the right tool for you.